# I have no idea what could be causing the error about graph API Call

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, device, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add and change extended properties of devices registered in AzureAD using C#.
But I am getting the following error, I don't know why...

Below is the part about the Graph API call. I used the document provided by MS Docs as it is, and it works normally in Graph API Explorer.

**[C# Code]**

```
var device = await graphclient.Devices
    .Request()
    .Filter(ftr)
    .Select("Id")
    .GetAsync();

string objectId = device.CurrentPage.First().Id.ToString().Trim();

var extattr = new Device
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
        {"extensionAttributes", "{\"extensionAttribute1\":\"BYOD-Device2\"}"}
    }
};

await graphclient.Devices[objectId]
     .Request()
     .UpdateAsync(extattr);
```

**[ErrorCode]**

```
Status Code: BadRequest
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: Request_BadRequest
Message: A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the property 'extensionAttributes'; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.
```

The current situation is that extensionAttribute1 has the value 'BYOD-Device'.

Is there anyone out there who can help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `extensionAttribute1` property is not a JSON string, but a JSON object. Try

```
AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
    {"extensionAttributes", new Dictionary<string, object>(){
        {"extensionAttribute1", "BYOD-Device2"}
    }}
}
```

Comment: I used the sample provided by MS Docs as it is, but the Docs themselves were incorrect information...ㅠㅠ

Comment: @CompileErr Glad it helped you) Sometimes docs can be outdated or maybe you copied a part and wrote the other part yourself; It happens. Also maybe consider upvoting & marking the answer. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment***

When using spectfic  `$filter` and `$search` query parameters ,make sure to use the ConsistencyLevel header set to eventual and $count to true

Headers:

```
ConsistencyLevel=eventual 
$count=true
```

***C# code:***

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
    new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
    new QueryOption("$search", "\"displayName:Android\"")
};
var device = await graphclient.Devices
    .Request()
    .Filter(ftr)
   .Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
    .Select("Id")
    .GetAsync();

string objectId = device.CurrentPage.First().Id.ToString().Trim();

var extattr = new Device
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
        {"extensionAttributes", "{\"extensionAttribute1\":\"BYOD-Device2\"}"}
    }
};

await graphclient.Devices[objectId]
     .Request()
     .UpdateAsync(extattr);
```

In azure ad extensionAttributes  can  be set while creation or updating device object.

And Supports **`filter`** **`when value is null`**

> $filter (eq, not, startsWith, and eq on null values).

Get the device details:

I checked in one of my subscriptions with  deviceId,
could get its details.

[image]

Normally new extension  attribute can be created for  which doesn’t have any previous value or value is **null** .

But here `extensionattribute1` has already had a value in your case.

```
"extensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute1": "BYOD-Device",
        "extensionAttribute2": null,
        "extensionAttribute3": null,
        "extensionAttribute4": null,
        "extensionAttribute5": null,
        "extensionAttribute6": null,
        "extensionAttribute7": null,
       ...
}
```

But as it already has some value , to update it either new extension with another number  has to be created or that attribute has to be explicitly made null and then updated.

```
 var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
        new QueryOption("$search", "\"displayName:Android\"")
    };
    var device = await graphclient.Devices
        .Request()
        .Filter(ftr)
       .Header("ConsistencyLevel","eventual")
        .Select("Id")
        .GetAsync();
    
    ......
DeviceId = "xxxxxxx",
     ....
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"extensionAttributes", "{\"extensionAttribute1\":\"BYOD-Device\"}"}
    }
};

await graphClient.Devices
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(device)
```

> Also note that some extension properties cannot be updated when using
> Linux OS

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/device?view=graph-rest-1.0